# Replace one section of a bigger list with a smaller list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists

```
list_a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
list_b=[3,555]
```

how do i merge `list_b` to `list_a` and replace values on the first matching value(3) hence producing the following output list

```
list_c=[1,2,3,555,5,6]
```

Note: numbers 3 and 4 from list_a were replaced with number 3 and 555 from list_b through first matching number(3) in `list_b` to `list_a`.

Comment: `i = list_a.index(list_b[0]); list_a[i: i+len(list_b)] = list_b`

Comment: @yatu this modifies the first list

Comment: You can just create a copy in that case @RiccardoBucco

Comment: @yatu did not see your comment before posting, apologies. Great minds, huh... ;-)

Comment: Ah no worries, pretty sure you didn't just copy this, not like you need to :D @cs95

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
idx = list_a.index(list_b[0])
list_c = list_a[:idx] + list_b + list_a[idx + len(list_b):]
```

This solution does not modify `list_a`, but creates a brand new list `list_c` containing the desired elements.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
# python3.8+
>>> list_a[(idx := list_a.index(list_b[0])):idx + len(list_b)] = list_b
>>> list_a
[1, 2, 3, 555, 5, 6]
```

```
# older pythons,
>>> idx = list_a.index(list_b[0])
>>> list_a[idx:idx + len(list_b)] = list_b
>>> list_a
[1, 2, 3, 555, 5, 6]
```

Which just selects the right slot to replace with the contents of the second list.